# Import data from bpmn file into one string/char value Matlab

Tags: matlab, import, bpmn

I have a consistent bpmn file (similar to xml file) and i would like to read it with matlab and store the all file data in one string or char attribute. I have tried with `textread(file, format)` but the best i can have is a 2358796x1 char and then assemble each line to recreate the file but it's a very long process.

Is there another function to do this ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://github.com/cortex-lab/MATLAB-tools/blob/master/xml2struct.m) `xml2struct.m` function, to read xml files and convert all the content to MATLAB struct variable.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Matlab ship with an [`xmlread` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xmlread.html). Have you taken a look at that?

Comment: Hmm. What's not working? I'm not familiar with BPMN, but from my brief googling, it seemed like BPMN files _were_ a dialect of XML (defined in the XPDL "BPMN serialization" specficiation).